# Create a forgot password with node Apisauce and react

Tags: node.js, react-native, api

Im trying to create a forgot password in my app with react, the api is working and its mailing me, but it dont redirect for where it should and trigger an error, here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import api from '../services/api'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { getPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-location';


styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    input:{
      
        height:40,
        width:200,
        margin: 40,
        borderColor:'gray',
        borderWidth: 1
      
    },
    Button:{
      flex: 1,
      height:30,
      width: 40,
      margin: 40,
      color: 'blue',
      borderWidth: 1,
      alignSelf:'flex-end'
    },
    Button2:{
      flex:1,
      height:20,
      width:30,
      color:'#f0f8ff',
      alignSelf:'flex-end',
      borderStyle: 'dashed'
    }
})


export default class forgotpass extends Component {
  state ={
    errorMessage: null,
    email:'',
   
  }
  signin = async() => {
    try{
      const response = await api.post('/auth/forgot_password',{
        email:this.state.email,
        
      })
  
      const {user, token} = response.data
      console.log(response.data)
  
      await AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        ['@backend:token', token],
        ['@backend:user', JSON.stringify(user)]
      ])

      this.props.navigation.navigate('Reset')
    }catch(response){
      this.setState({errorMessage: response.data.error})
      console.log(err)
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.Container}>
           { this.state.errorMessage && <Text>{ this.state.errorMessage }</Text> }
        
        <TextInput  style={styles.input} placeholder={'Enter your email for confirmation'} 
          <TextInput  style={styles.input} placeholder={'Enter your email for confirmation'} 
                   onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({email: value})}/>
        <Button  style={styles.Button} onPress={this.signin} title="Confirm"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
    
}
```

And I cant see the real error because it just shoots :
Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context.t0.data.error')

can you help me ?